# how to use PRDownloader library to download file

Tags: android, download, android-library

I want to download file by using PRDownloader library but I have two equations

**first:** how to use the library to download file ? ...

**second:** what must I put in `String dirPath` ?....

**My MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        PRDownloader.initialize(this);

        PRDownloaderConfig config = PRDownloaderConfig.newBuilder()
                .setDatabaseEnabled(true)
                .build();
        PRDownloader.initialize(getApplicationContext(), config);




        String url = "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/mohammed-1f35b.appspot.com/o/fear-storynory-jana.mp3?alt=media&token=4d0fc7a3-2b95-4ddd-8ecc-c792a09ab539";
        String fileName ="myPhoto";
        String dirPath = "????????";

        int downloadId = PRDownloader.download(url, dirPath, fileName)
                .build()
                .setOnStartOrResumeListener(new OnStartOrResumeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onStartOrResume() {

                    }
                })
                .setOnPauseListener(new OnPauseListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPause() {

                    }
                })
                .setOnCancelListener(new OnCancelListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCancel() {

                    }
                })
                .setOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onProgress(Progress progress) {

                    }
                })
                .start(new OnDownloadListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDownloadComplete() {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Error error) {

                    }
                });


        PRDownloader.pause(downloadId);
        PRDownloader.cancel(downloadId);

    }




}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example how to download with PRDownloader:

```
private int downloadFile(url){

    String fileName = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
    String dirPath = getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath()+File.separator+"downloads";
    //String dirPath = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+File.separator+"downloads";

    return /*download id*/ PRDownloader.download(url, dirPath, fileName)
            .build()
            .start(new OnDownloadListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDownloadComplete() {
                    log("download complete!");
                }
                @Override
                public void onError(Error error) {
                    log("onError: " +error.toString());
                }
            });

}
```

`fileName` is what the file will be stored as once downloaded.
`dirPath` is where it will be stored.

Example on how to call it:

```
String url = "https://www.your-url.com/files/file.txt"
int downloadId = downloadFile(url);
```

You can store files either on internal storage with `getFilesDir()`, or external storage with `getExternalStorageDirectory()`.

You do not need any special permissions to store to internal storage, however the data will not be accessible by the user. It will also be deleted, if the user deletes the app.

If you store on external storage, you need to request permission from the user. He will be able to see the files (using a file browser, for example).

Comment: {"connectionException":{"detailMessage":"unexpected end of stream","stackTrace":[],"suppressedExceptions":[]},"isConnectionError":true,"isServerError":false,"responseCode":0} for larger files this issue raised ost of times even internet have a proper connection. Did you faced this issue ?

Comment: Sathish Gadde: I suggest you contact the developer, or open an issue on the project page.

Comment: I am getting error when this library try download file but the file is already presented in the directory. How to replace the old file while downloading.

Answer (score 3):

Dir path is where you want to write the file on your device (*Like where you want to download it*).
It can be `context.getFilesDir().toString()` this gives you path of your local files.

When it downloads the file, `onDownloadComplete()` will be called, after that you can access your file 
like this: 
 `Uri fileURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, authorities, new File(getFilesDir() +"/" + filename));`

This **won't** work unless you don't create your **File Provider**. it's like you can't use device storage without permission so you have to create **provider**.
This is very good reference for that: [FileProvider](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider). 
Good luck.

Answer (score -2):

dirPath is the path of the location that you want save the downloaded file

like : `"/sdcard/downloads"`

and you can use this library like the code below:

```
 downloadID = PRDownloader.download(url,path,"hellow.mp4")
        .build()
        .setOnStartOrResumeListener(new OnStartOrResumeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onStartOrResume() {

            }
        })
        .setOnPauseListener(new OnPauseListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPause() {

            }
        })
        .setOnCancelListener(new OnCancelListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCancel() {

            }
        })
        .setOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgress(Progress progress) {


            }
        })
        .start(new OnDownloadListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDownloadComplete() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Error error) {

            }


        });
```

Running the code above will start your download

And finally use `downloadId` for pause , resume or cancel a special download case

Comment: They should have provided a way to access the 'prdownloader.db' database or call it to resume the downloads automatically after closing the application.