# How to Change Download Directory

Tags: android, directory, download, patch

How To Change getrootPatch Dir to Public Directory. When I download file with This Directory, its Downloading to Adroid/Data/app.package.com folder..??

I talk about This question [how to use PRDownloader library to download file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50418110/how-to-use-prdownloader-library-to-download-file)

```
public static String getRootDirPath(Context context) {
    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(Environment.getExternalStorageState())) {
        File file = ContextCompat.getExternalFilesDirs(context.getApplicationContext(),
                null)[0];
        return file.getAbsolutePath();
    } else {
        return context.getApplicationContext().getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath();
    }
}
```

Comment: Look at the Environment class. And... Your question has nothing to do with downloading as you can see.

Comment: look at here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50418110/how-to-use-prdownloader-library-to-download-file

Comment: With PRDownload library everythinh when you looking to download, just downloading to android/data/app-package folders.... I'm looking to download it to download folder or other one not in root folders ???

Comment: Well then you have to change getExternalFilesDirs. There is a suitable replacement in Environment class as i said before. And changing a directory path has nothing to do with downloading. I said that before.

Comment: `downloading to android/data/app-package ` No it then downloads to /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/app-package/files as that is getExternalFilesDir.